# Strong params issue in rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a many-to-many model ProductCategory product_category (joint-table) and
I'm having issue with nesting the parameter in the ProductsController. The error I keep getting is that its unpermitted params `category_ids` but I have nested it in the strong product params.

I took a picture of the important parts of the code. Please take a look and let me know thank you. Here is the most important part of the code I think:

```rb
<%= form_with(model: [:user, @product], local: true) do |f|%>
  <h4>Category</h4> 
  <div class="dropdown-trigger btn"> 
    <%= f.collection_select(:category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name) %>   
  </div>
  
  <h4>Product Name:</h4> 
  <%= f.text_field :name  %><br/>

  <h4>Product Price:</h4> 
  <%= f.number_field :price, value: @product.price ? '%.2f' % @product.price : nil, min: 0, step: 0.01 %>$<br/>

  <h4>Product Description:</h4> 
  <%= f.text_field :description  %><br/>
  <h4>Product Image (recommended)</h4> 
  <%= f.file_field :image  %><br/>
```

The `require` in `ProductsController`:

```rb
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name, :price, :description, :image,  category_ids: [])
end
```

And the relevant parts of `Product` and `ProductCategory` model.

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :product_categories
  has_many :categories, though: :product_categories

  has_one_attached :image
end

class ProductCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :product_categories
  has_many :products, though: :product_categories
end
```

[code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYgoD.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please don't include screenshots of code or errors in your question. It often makes it difficult to read, you can't cut-and-paste it to reproduce a problem, and they cannot be searched on. Can you please edit your question to include code from your models' definitions?

Comment: What does `params` contain? Does adding `multiple: true` to your collection_select call help?

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving an "unpermitted params category_ids" error, because you first need to declare in your Product model the following:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories , allow_destroy: true
```

Once that is done, you should start receiving all the category_ids info, really nested inside your params.

However, I fully recommend DO NOT perform on your views and partials an ActiveRecord query over your DB. For example:

```
  <div class="dropdown-trigger btn"> 
    <%= f.collection_select(:category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name) %>   
  </div>
```

That is not advisable. Instead, you should receive from your controller the whole set of categories. The only function on the view in this case is to fill the data by the user, to select the categories, and then after a submit to send all that information back to the controller. That's all. Not performing any kind of query. It's true that you **can** do it. I mean, it is physically possible to do it there on that view, or even to do it on a helper (also wrong, a helper is to perform additional actions over resources already loaded or received from controllers), but MVC means the separation of duties for several reasons.

Anyway, in your case I would choose to go more or less with something like this:

**On products_controller.rb:**

```
def edit
  @categories_to_assign = product_service.get_categories_to_assign(@product)
end

def product_service
 ProductService
end

def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name, :price, :description, :image,  categories_to_assign: [])
end
```

**On product_service.rb it gets the categories:**

```
def self.get_categories_to_assign(product)
  categories_scope.where.not(id: product.categories.map(&:id)).map do |category|
    ["#{category.name}", category.id]
  end
end

def self.categories_scope()
  Category
end
```

**Then on the edit/new view:**

```
<%
  categories_to_assign = @categories_to_assign || []
%>

<% content_for :products_main_content do %>
  <div id="edit_product_content">
    <%= render partial: 'products/form', locals: {
        product: product,
        return_to: return_to,
        categories_to_assign: categories_to_assign
    } %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Then on the _form.html.erb partial:**

```
<%
  categories_to_assign = local_assigns.fetch(:categories_to_assign, [])
%>

      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h2 class="panel-title"><%= t('products.categories.title') %></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="form-horizontal" id="categories_container" data-sjr-placeholder>
            <%= render partial: 'products/categories', locals: {f: f, categories_to_assign: categories_to_assign} %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**And finally on the _categories.html.erb partial:**

```
<%
  categories_to_assign = local_assigns.fetch(:categories_to_assign, [])
%>

  <% if categories_to_assign.present? %>
    <%= select_tag "#{f.object_name}[categories_to_assign][]", options_for_select(categories_to_assign), {id: "#{f.object_name}_categories_to_assign", include_blank: true, multiple: true, class: 'form-control', data: {placeholder: t('products.form.select_category')}} %>
  <% end %>
```

As you can see, the general idea is passing the pertinent information from the controller, after been properly retrieved on the product_service (you should add it), and then it goes to the edit/new view and then it finally goes down into the nested partials. That way everything is separated in its respective areas of responsibilities.

Comment: thank you so much for the help, i actually fixed the issue by passing category_ids as an attribute and that solved the problem there also found out that passing a class to the form collection_select causes an issue with the parameters so i removed the class for that and that actually allowed the params to get passed and rendered, but i really like what you did there, so i actually might adjust my code to that thank you again i appreciate it :D